# InvalidOperationException in the ReorderListBox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, reorderlist

I'm using the [ReorderListbox](https://reorderlistbox.codeplex.com/) from https://reorderlistbox.codeplex.com/ in my WP8 application. It's great piece of work and deserved a great appreciation.

I'm setting the ItemSource for the ReorderListBox is as follows:

```
        var Query = from it in AppDB.TableName
                    select it;

        ReorderListBox.ItemsSource = Query.ToList();
```

The list shows the items perfectly and no problem occurs but When I reorder the list, there's an error occured and breaks the application. Here's the exception:

[image]

So, It clearly says that it can't works on read only collections. So, How to make it work to my solution. I'm getting the list from the sqlce database.

Comment: I don't know that control but keep in mind that when you remove an item from the list then you might have to adjust the insertion index too.

Answer (score 0):

`Query.ToList()` returns a readonly list. Try creating a new List like

```
ReorderListBox.ItemsSource = new List<T>(Query.ToList());
```

where `T` is the type of the items behind `TableName`

But, i think you are better of using bindings, and binding your ItemSource to a `ObservableCollection<T>` that lives in your View/ViewModel and just adding items to that collection.